# What bulbs do I need for a Micra K11 dashboard?

Tags: nissan, micra

In my Nissan Micra K11 dashboard, the backlights for the clock and left-hand side of the speedo have stopped working. The dashboard is similar to the one pictured below, with the central clock and fuel/speedo/engine temperature gauges, no rev counter.

What bulb(s) do I need to repair them, and do they need to be all replaced at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

'K11' covers a lot of Micra's. The bulbs come in a couple of varieties: Held captive in a plastic holder which comes with the bulb or the usual capless bulb. It is not necessary to change all of the bulbs at the same time, although prudence might say... "while one or two have failed so others may fail soon"...

Comment: Full car model is K11C, Nissan Micra Activ, 2001 model.